# How to style Bottom Tab Navigator in reactnative

Tags: react-native, tabnavigator

I'm trying to create a basic bottom tab navigator without any icons but I can't figure out how to style the label text
I need to center the text and make it bigger
[here's what i have so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rP52t.png)

ive tried using tabBarOptions and screenOptions but nothing seems to work

Comment: please paste the code in text, don't use image

Answer (score 1):

Use [tabBarLabelStyle](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator#tabbarlabelstyle) to style a label and [tabBarIconStyle](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator#tabbariconstyle) an icon. Something like this:

```
<Tab.Navigator
  screenOptions={{
    tabBarLabelStyle: { fontSize: 24, padding: 8 },
    tabBarIconStyle: { display: 'none' }
  }}>
  <Tab.Screen name="Upload" component={UploadScreen} />
  <Tab.Screen name="Create" component={CreateScreen} />
</Tab.Navigator>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check out my code. I have used icons and also updated the text sizes.

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {View} from "react-native";
import {NavigationContainer} from "@react-navigation/native";
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";
import Ionicons from "react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons";

import SearchScreen from "../screens/search"
import TransactionScreen from "../screens/transaction"

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default class BottomTabNavigator extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
     <NavigationContainer>
     <Tab.Navigator
     screenOptions={({route})=>({
       tabBarIcon: ({focused, color, size}) =>{
         let iconName;

         if(route.name==="Transaction"){
           iconName="logo-apple"
         }else if(route.name==="Search"){
           iconName="search"
         }

         return (
                <Ionicons
                  name={iconName}
                  size={size}
                  color={color}
                  size={size}
                />
              );
       }

     })}
     tabBarOptions={{
            activeTintColor: "#FFFFFF",
            inactiveTintColor: "black",
            style: {
              height: 80,
              borderTopWidth: 0,
              backgroundColor: "#9DFD24"
            },
            labelStyle: {
              fontSize: 20,
            },
            labelPosition: "beside-icon",
            tabStyle: {
              marginTop: 25,
              marginLeft: 10,
              marginRight: 10,
              borderRadius: 450,
              borderWidth: 3,
              alignItems: "center",
              justifyContent: "center",
              backgroundColor: "grey"
            }
          }}
     
      >
      <Tab.Screen name="Transaction" component={TransactionScreen}/>
      <Tab.Screen name="Search" component={SearchScreen}/>


     </Tab.Navigator>
     </NavigationContainer>

    )
  }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).